# How do I convert a FileContentResult to a FileStreamResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net, filecontentresult, filestreamresult

I have a FileContentResult obtained from a byte array and want to turn it into a FileStreamResult. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, I don't know much about MVC but it sounds like you shouldn't *need* to do this. If you have code which depends on `FileStreamResult`, see if you could make it depend on `FileResult` instead, which is the base class of both `FileStreamResult` and `FileContentResult`.

But otherwise, you could always use:

```
var streamResult = new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(contentResult.FileContents),
                                        contentResult.ContentType)
streamResult.FileDownloadName = contentResult.FileDownloadName;
// You could use an object initializer instead of a separate statement, of course.
```

Comment: Hey this worked for the question I answered! Thanks for that. :)